# How to get around the event bubble using jQuery's: .live()

Tags: javascript, dom, jquery, slideup

Here is the code in question:

```
$(".navItems>ul>li").live('click', function() {
  var selectorID = $(this).attr('id');
  $(".infoList").slideUp('fast', function(){
    switchTabInfo(selectorID);
  });
  function switchTabInfo(selectorID){
    var actionID = selectorID.substring(4);
    actionID = "#" + actionID;
    $(actionID).slideDown();
  }
})
```

So in short i have a these .infoList classes with id names tied to back to the nav li id. 
That lists item's id might be nav_testsHistory for example. With all the content boxes hidden by class name this javascript makes a pleasing slide up, down effect.

But the third content box flickers as will the second one after a third box push. It slides up and down a second unnecessary time.

If I add an alert like this:

```
$(".navItems>ul>li").live('click', function(){
  var selectorID = $(this).attr('id');
  $(".infoList").slideUp('fast', function(){
  switchTabInfo(selectorID);
  alert('bubble');
});
```

The alert fires 3 times?!

So my research took to reading about the event bubble. What I cannot find is how to check if it has been fired. I have not tried setting an input val and doing a tf test around the nested slider action. Cause that's crude.

More info, all the code above is in a function, which is in an init() function, which is called on document ready. That's the only js file besides jquery 1.3.2.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Show us the HTML, and confess if you've made the grievous mistake of having more than one element with the same "id" value.

Comment: Your calls to `$('.infoList').slideUp(...)` will always find *all* "infoList" class elements and make them slide up.  Is that really what you want?

Comment: k. right now theres 3 divs, 
<div class="infoList" id="testsHistory_list" style="display:block">
</div>
<div class="infoList" id="testsPending_list">
</div>
<div class="infoList" id="moreInfo_list">
</div>

That's straight outta the code. I thought i had hit good with event.stopPropagation() but alas issue persists. 

I must use .live because the html in question is being injected into the document using .load.

Comment: @Nick, it's not one event bubbling, it's one event calling the function (that contains alert) 3 times for each `.infoList`.

Comment: oh yea, i have also tried attaching return false.

Comment: @Nick: I think Nick Craver's answer might be most helpful here. You should study his solution carefully. The point is to limit your selection of `.infoList` elements.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your problem is bubbling, but in your selector.  You're selecting by class, so all the classes will run that animation (all 3, which is why you get 3 alerts).

I think in this case:

```
$(".infoList").slideUp('fast', function(){
  switchTabInfo(selectorID);
});
```

What you may want is this:

```
$(".infoList:visible").slideUp('fast', function(){
  switchTabInfo(selectorID);
});
```

Currently you're selecting all `class="infoList"` and sliding them up, if you just want to hide the one that's visible, add the `:visible` selector.  A `.stop()` would also eliminate some queue issues, like this overall:

```
$(".navItems>ul>li").live('click', function() {
  var selectorID = $(this).attr('id');
  $(".infoList:visible").slideUp('fast', function(){
    $("#" + selectorID.substring(4)).stop().slideDown();
    switchTabInfo(selectorID);
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(".infoList")` is not bound to any context so it is possible that in other `li` elements you have those as well and you fire `slideUp` for all.

You might want to change it to:

```
$(".infoList", this).slideUp...
```

Comment: This is my first time to post on this website. And wow thanks so much.!

:visible .. yes!

Thats so nice. You know it's kind of a matter of picking up my laziness. Trying to just slide all up like that..;)